# How to create a custom exception by extending throwable and using a try-catch block to catch the exception?

Tags: java, exception

I have a class that is called n(bad programming practice, this i know) I have it extend Throwable and when to add my own test exception. I do not want to throw if from the method stub like in Code Example 2 but would rather some how use a try catch. Is there a way to do this? I have seend some examples, in fact this is where I got this example but nothing seems to be working.

I did read that normally you would not want to extend Throwable but rather Exception or RunTimeException but I want to see how this works. I think that if you extend Trhowable than you have access to all of the other exceptions as well. So some code below might work this way.

```
    try {

     } catch (myOwnException err) {

     } catch (Exception err) {

     } finally {

     }
```

Question: How to throw my exception (n) with a try-catch block rather than having the method stub throw the exception?

Code Example 1:

```
public class newthrow extends MyNewException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static void main(String[] pizza){
        try {

        } catch (MyNewException e) { <-- Unreachable catch block for n. This exception 
                                    is never thrown from the try statement body

        }
    }
}

class MyNewException extends Throwable {
MyNewException() {
}
 }

public class newthrow extends MyNewException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static void main(String[] pizza) throws n {
    }
}

class MyNewException extends Throwable {
    MyNewException() {
    }
  }
```

Code Example 2: (Compiles -- but not really what I was looking for

```
public class newthrow extends MyNewException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static void main(String[] pizza) throws n {
    }
}

class MyNewException extends Throwable {
        MyNewException() {
        }
}
```

I have used exceptions before. I know that Java provides a ton of them for different aspects of program. I want to determine the best way to build my own exceptions.

I know that this will work below.

code: with Exception extended.

```
class myNewExc extends Exception {
    myNewExc() {

    }
}
```

This is what I am trying to avoid below. Code that throws after a method stub because I think that you have to deal with this then in a class that extends another class that has this type of syntax.

```
      public static void main(String[] pizza) throws n, myNewExc{
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some core concepts about exceptions and how they work.  Suggest you read through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: You don't need to explain that `n` is a terrible name. Change it (and `newthrow` as well because class name convention is `UpperCamelCase`),  people will comment anyways :p

Comment: An exception class is a Java class like any other... Not sure what you want to achieve? The only difference with "regular" classes is that you can `throw`/`catch` them

Comment: When I extend the Exception class to make my own class, how do I do it so that I can use it in a try-catch block rather than in the throws method stub?

Comment: @DougHauf Your question doesn't make any sense. You can throw any exception with throw new MyException() and you can catch any exception in catch(MyException e).

Comment: I have tried that catch MyException but there is an error so does the exception have to be extend in the class definition at the beginning.   public class someOtherClassHere extends MyException {

Comment: @PaulSweatte That is not a duplicate for this question